# Review test passed after only reading comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, late-answers

I think I have found a bug. I was reviewing "late answers" on Stack Overflow. I've clicked the *show comments* button, on the original question, and immediately after that I got a message, that it was only a test, and I passed. Shouldn't I pass the test only AFTER I made some action?

Comment: Well, the audit's designed to test that you're paying attention, and if you're going to take the time to read the comments you're paying at least a bit of attention... But that does seem a bit hasty :)

Comment: I think it is enough, as the fact you are investigating it, shows you are paying attention, it is not for a nobel prize- oh and it's not bug, it's by design

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **Congratulations!**
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying
>   attention. **You passed**.

Review audits are made for finding robo-reviewers who are not paying any attention to the review posts by just clicking on the *No action needed button* to increase their review count/ for gaining badges.

By clicking on the Add/Show comments button, you were paying attention to the review. This could also be considered as an action for a review audit.

Comment: But main drawback of this is that robo can easily pass the audit just by clicking add/show comment every time.

Comment: @hims056, add/show comment button could not be available for every audit, and there are many other easy way to pass the audit for ex, clicking on flag button is the best of all.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't know that fact (button could not be available for every audit).